# Javascript table cell on click event?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a game board that has click functions on every cell, but every time i click on a cell the only one that gets affected is the very last cell. 
i would appreciate some help on this.
heres my code for the table:

```
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var NUM_ROWS = 6;
var NUM_COLS = 6;
for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = 'images/image0.png';
    td.appendChild(img);
    td.addEventListener("click", function() {
      img.src = 'images/image1.png';
    });
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  board.appendChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: it works for me, what is your browser , me it is chrome what do you see in console (F12)

Comment: I'm also using chrome. nothing comes up in the console. I just can't seem to figure out why the only cell thats changing is the very last one. i just need it so the cell that i choose changes

Comment: you have to put img in a closure

Comment: If img is the only child of td do this: `td.addEventListener("click", function() {
      td.childNodes[0].src = 'images/image1.png';
    });`

Comment: What do you mean by in a closure?

Comment: i can't post answer because it is marked as duplicated so, it is a function, because if you declare img in a function it will not be replace by the next iteration because the scope is different.

Comment: var board = document.getElementById("board");
 var NUM_ROWS = 6;
 var NUM_COLS = 6;
 for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");
   for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {

Comment: (function(){
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = 'images/image0.png';
      td.appendChild(img);
      td.addEventListener("click", function() {
          img.src = 'images/image1.png';
      });
  })()
   }

Comment: tr.appendChild(td);
}
board.appendChild(tr);

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to point `img` child first using `document.body.childNodes[0];`.

```
 td.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var img = this.childNodes[0];
      img.src = 'images/image1.png';//use this not img
    });
```

**Solution:**

```js
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var NUM_ROWS = 6;
var NUM_COLS = 6;
for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = 'images/image0.png';
    td.appendChild(img);
    td.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var img = this.childNodes[0];
      console.log('Source Before Clicking');
      console.log(img.src);
      img.src = 'images/image1.png';//use this not img
      console.log('Source Afer Clicking');
      console.log(img.src);
    });
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  board.appendChild(tr);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">

</div>
```

Comment: lol you re changing the src of the td

Comment: The click doesn't work when i try this.

Comment: Try edited answer.You have to point img of child first.

Comment: @ bormat see edited answer.

Comment: @swen see edited answer.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question actually, I want to add an id to the cells, so like row 1/col 1 would have an id of 1, row 1/col 2 would have an id of 2, and etc. In order to do that would i just have append another child?